Why does calling map() on an array yield an extraneous value in an Xcode Playground
My code:
import UIKit

let arr: [Int] = [1, 2, 3]
let result = arr.map { x in x + 2 }
result

Here is what an Xcode 16.2 Playground shows for the results:

Where does the extra 5 come from on line 4?
adsfhasdkfkahjsdflasdhhf
asdfasdklfhkasdjhfksadhf
asdfkhasdfkhjasdflkasdfhksd

I think it's showing the last result of the two variables on that line - result, and x.

You can click on the rectangle beside that result to expand it. It is actually two results squished into one line.

By hovering over each of those squares, parts of your code get highlighted to indicate what the result is referring to. "[3, 4, 5]" highlights the word "result" in let result = ...

and "5" highlights x + 2.

This is the value of x + 2 the last time it has been evaluated. To see the other values of x + 2, click on the square next to "5", and it will display a graph showing the value of x + 2 over time. By clicking on a point in the graph, you can read its value.

